# Self Incrimination

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Does anyone think it may be a good idea to warn people not to post anything that can incriminate them? If they wish to ask about something that is potentially incriminating they should at least phrase that they're asking for a friend or even better in a completely theoretical way?

Could we make such notice when people ask a question for the first time on this SE?

Answer (score 3):

Why? This is the internet. There's nothing on Twitter or Facebook or Instagram that says that things they post can incriminate them. There's an argument that this is a Law site and people might mistakenly come and post such information, but there's no reason to think that they're not really aware of the public nature of the site.

There's also a note in the [Disclaimer](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/disclaimer):

> Further, these are not privileged communication or attorney work product, and no right to privacy exists. Any opinions expressed are the opinions of the individual author and may not reflect the opinions of Stack Exchange, or other users.

Also, as we learned from [How do people publicly admit to criminal activity and not typically get arrested?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/3381/58), even admitting to doing something has no evidentiary value.

Unfortunately, we can't protect everyone from themselves. I see some merit in telling people that this isn't a legal *advice* site but a legal *information* and *education* site, but telling people that things they post on the internet may incriminate them? Seems like common sense and general knowledge.